# Database loop statement returns an error "wrong number or types of arguments in call to PUT_LINE

Tags: oracle, loops, iteration, database-cursor

I'm new to Oracle programming (started coding a month ago).

I've written codes that contain a cursor to do iteration, However it doesn't return the expected result. In order to troubleshoot, I've written the following code to test the basic loop statement.

```
begin
  for cursor_TEST in (select column_name
                                      from TABLE_1
                     )
                                     
  loop
  
               dbms_output.put_line(cursor_TEST);              

  end loop;
end;
```

I thought this simple code should print the values of cursor_TEST, However it returns the error "wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PUT_LINE'"

Could you please advise? Is there anything wrong with this loop statement?
I thought it should work because I strictly followed the syntax of LOOP statement in Oracle....
Thank you

Comment: What data type do you expect a "cursor" to be? (In your case it is an implicit cursor, but that is irrelevant for my question.) If it is not of string data type, it should be a data type that can be converted to a string - for example a number, or a date (using implicit conversion to string using a default format, etc.) You can't convert an associative array to a string, for example; you would get the same error. So, back to my question: what kind of data type to you expect "cursor" to be? What do you mean by "printing" the "value" of a cursor to the screen?

Comment: Just guessing you want `dbms_output.put_line(cursor_test.column_name);` It would likely be more helpful for you to ask about the real problem (the one that made you think about running this small test), to see why ***that*** didn't work.

Comment: Hi Mathguy, Yes this works! "dbms_output.put_line(cursor_test.column_name);" Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` expects a character string as input. It will not "print the values of cursor_TEST" - you need to tell it what precisely you want printed. For example:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('column_name=' || cursor_TEST.column_name);
```

would print the value of the column `column_name` in the `cursor_TEST` loop variable.